# Exporting Interactive 3D Graph to Web (with axes and legends)

Tags: image3d, web

I would like to put a 3D Mathematica plot online where the viewer could rotate the graph. I have searched previous questions and found:

[Can Mathematica produce manipulatable 3D plots for deployment on the web?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81104/can-mathematica-produce-manipulatable-3d-plots-for-deployment-on-the-web)

I have tried these solutions, however they do not produce axes or plot legends. I was wondering if there was a way to include axes and plot legends in the .x3d export.

Thanks for your help in advanced!