# Optimizing some code for WolframCloud deployment/publishing

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, wolfram-cloud, guidelines

I am working on creating a demonstration and came across an instance where my code works fine on my machine locally but breaks down when deployed to the cloud (so that it can be publicly accessed). I really do want to deploy it; can someone help make it render/work from the cloud?

Here is the code:

```
Func[x_, u1_, u2_] := Exp[-(x - u1)^2/2] + Exp[-(x - u2)^2/2] 
Sensor[loc_, u1_, u2_] := Graphics3D@{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point@Join[loc,{Func[loc[[1]], u1, u2]}]} 
SurfPlot[f_, u1_, u2_, sens1_, sens2_] := Show[Plot3D[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints
-> 50, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], Sensor[sens1, u1, u2], Sensor[sens2, u1, u2]]
TwoDPlot[u1_, u2_] := Plot[{Exp[-(x - u1)^2/2], Exp[-(x - u2)^2/2]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRegion -> Full]
```

That sets up a 3D surface and two red points on the surface; also a 2D representation of them is made. Next, I want to be able to move the two "sensors" around in manipulate, so I am going to set up a [`LocatorPane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html).

```
LocSlider[loc_, init_] := {{loc, init, "Position of Sensor"}, {-5,-5}, {5, 5}, ControlType -> None}
LocBox = {Gray, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]};
SensorBullsEye := {Black, Line[{{-5, #[[2]]}, {5, #[[2]]}}], Line[{{#[[1]], -5}, {#[[1]], 5}}]} &;
```

There is a relationship between the 2D plot and the location of the sensors so after defining a helper function for that, I call `Manipulate`.

```
Phase[u1_, u2_] := Abs[u2 - u1]
SenseDiff[{x1_, x2_}] := Abs[x2 - x1]
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{{SurfPlot[Func[x, u1, u2], u1, u2, xy1, xy2], 
    TwoDPlot[u1, 
     u2 - (Phase[u1, u2] - SenseDiff[First /@ {xy1, xy2}])]}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large],
 {{u1, -2.5, ""}, 0, 0, ControlType -> None}, {{u2, 2.5, ""}, 0, 0, 
  ControlType -> None},
 Evaluate@LocSlider[xy1, {2, 2}], Evaluate@LocSlider[xy2, {-2, -2}],
 Dynamic[LocatorPane[Dynamic[{xy1, xy2}], 
   Graphics[{LocBox, {Dynamic[SensorBullsEye /@ {xy1, xy2}]}}, 
    ImageSize -> 100]]], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

This works fine locally on my Mac, but it hangs when published using WolframCloud.

[image]

Here is the [published version](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8d365716-7565-4d85-a72b-61e0cabdb5f3). Can someone show me what I can do better to make the deployed version work? I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81106/42145) answer but I haven't played around with the CDF format much.  What are some general principles to keep in mind when writing notebooks that are intended to deployed/interactive?

I understand that WolframCloud has kernel memory and computation limitations, so my intention is **not** to use it as a real-time computing resource for anything like data-science. But I feel something simple like this should be do-able.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple oneliner which kind of works.
Check out the published version here: [public cloud link](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/gluonvision/dyntest).
I personally still find most of these cloud-deployed Manipulate (or DynamicModule) toy-examples way too slow, but maybe someone from Wolfram has a clever trick to get a similar responsiveness as in a local notebook?

```
   SystemOpen @ 
  CloudDeploy[#, "somecode",Permissions->"Public"]& @
DynamicModule[{xy1 = {2, 2}, xy2 = {-2, -2}, u1 = -2.5, u2 = 2.5},
  Column @ {
    LocatorPane[ Dynamic[{xy1, xy2}], 
                 Dynamic @ Graphics[{LocBox,Map[SensorBullsEye]@{xy1,xy2}}, ImageSize -> 100]
    ]
    ,
    Row[{ Dynamic @ SurfPlot[Func, u1, u2, xy1, xy2],
          Dynamic @ TwoDPlot[u1, u2 - (Phase[u1, u2] - SenseDiff[First /@ {xy1, xy2}])]
    }]
  }
  ,
  Initialization :> (
    Func = Function[{x,u1,u2},Exp[-(x - u1)^2 / 2] + Exp[-(x - u2)^2 / 2]];
    Sensor[loc_, u1_, u2_] := Graphics3D @ {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point @ Join[loc, {Func[loc[[1]], u1, u2]}]}; 
    SurfPlot[f_Function, u1_, u2_, sens1_, sens2_] := Show[
        Plot3D[f[x,u1,u2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
      , Sensor[sens1, u1, u2], Sensor[sens2, u1, u2], ImageSize -> Medium
    ];
    TwoDPlot[u1_, u2_] := Plot[{Exp[-(x - u1)^2 / 2], Exp[-(x - u2)^2 / 2]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRegion -> Full, ImageSize -> Medium];
    LocBox = {Gray, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]};
    Phase[u1_, u2_] := Abs[u2 - u1];
    SenseDiff[{x1_, x2_}] := Abs[x2 - x1];
    SensorBullsEye = {Black, Line[{{-5, #[[2]]}, {5, #[[2]]}}], Line[{{#[[1]], -5}, {#[[1]], 5}}]} &)
, 
SaveDefinitions->False
]
```